# How can I get more item into single card view like ListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

This is my current output I need those item into single card.

[image]

How can I get more item into single card view like list view, here I have more than 6 value. I want to need those item into single card .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="#15579d"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LV01_TV02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="chgdhgv"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/LV01_TV03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="cbhdchfgf"
                android:textColor="#808080"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: can you please share the desired output screenshot for better understanding

Comment: Do you want this 6 cards in one card view??

Answer (score 0):

change these attributes in your cardview to this ( you must remove margin + corner radius )

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
```